# Lecturer "in Courses" vs "of Courses" vs "at Courses": What's the correct preposition?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to add my experience as an online lecturer to my LinkedIn profile details.

Should I use "Lecturer *in*, lecturer *of*, or lecturer *at* Online Courses" as the job title, or consider a completely different preposition altogether?

Comment: You can avoid the issue entirely by saying that you "lectured online courses on hyperspace wormhole engine design" or whatever it was.

Comment: If you really want to use that construct "Lecturer for online courses" sounds most natural to me.

Comment: Be clear:  Is "Online Courses" the name of a business or organization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to EL&U Garnagar,

Here's an example from [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lecturer):

> He's a lecturer **in** French at Oxford.

Running a quick [search](https://www.google.co.jp/search?site=&source=hp&btnG=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&q=%22lecturer%20in%22) through Google can help you in a couple of ways:

1. You will be able to see which of the prepositions is most widely used in that particular context. For example "lecturer in" scores an impressive 13,800,000 hits, as compared to "lecturer of" with 646,000.
2. You may stumble onto useful sources, such as [this one](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lecturer-in-or-lecturer-on.2068917/), suggesting that:

> Generally someone is a lecturer **in** a particular field who lectures **on** a specific topic.
>
> e.g. *She was just hired as a lecturer **in** genetics. If you are looking for a lecturer **on** recombinant DNA, she will be available to speak.*

Don't let the 11,500,000 hits on "lecturer at" fool you.
Although common, "lecturer **at**" is used to indicate the place (or even the time) of lecturing, not the subject being taught.

> - *She is a lecturer **at** Yale*
> - *He used to be a lecturer **at** the time.*

Here's how you might fill out your LinkedIn details, should you be willing to disclose the courses' specific topic(s) and modify the initial "Lecturer ***preposition*** Online Courses" structure into something more natural:

> Garnagar - Online Courses Lecturer **in** [topic].

Comment: Your sources don't support your recommendation. Your sources only support "lecturer in a subject" but "online courses" isn't a subject.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Precisely why the final line of my answer appears in the extended format in which it does. On one hand, to indicate the correct use of "in" in the "lecturer" context. On the other, to suggest the possibility of the OP modifying the original "Lecturer *preposition* Online Courses" model into something, which it would appear both you and I agree on, judging by your recommendation to "avoid the issue entirely", more conventional.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand how any of your sources justify "Lecturer in online courses on [topic]", which seems like a very unnatural construction to me. The only way I can see your sources justifying that usage would be if "online courses" was a field of study and the intended meaning was "I gave lectures whose subject was how too run online courses" rather than "I gave online lectures whose subject was something else."

Comment: @David Richerby You are quite right in saying that the sources quoted are not pertinent.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I agree. The structure does seem a bit off. I definitely see the logic in the latter part of your comment. Perhaps there is another way to approach this. Please check the edit. Phrased this way, the example adheres to the sources in regard to the use of preposition and addresses the issue of online courses not being a field of study by itself.